# Windows 10 Uninstall Desktop Applications from Search

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall

Before Windows 10 I used to remove unwanted Desktop Applications by clicking on Start and typing 'Uninstall [Application Name]'. The relevant uninstall link would then appear.

This no longer seems to work on Windows 10 (even though some times I am able to see the uninstall shortcuts momentarily - it seems as if the system doesn't want to show these items).

Any ideas on whether this can be changed?

Comment: If the Start Search finds the program in question, right-click it and click "uninstall".

Comment: It was probably finding results because certain programs will create a shortcut called "Uninstall (program name)" in the start menu. The program you're trying to uninstall right now clearly hasn't done that, so there's nothing for the search function to find. There's no intelligence to do it automatically.

Comment: The programs are only shown momentarily (maybe for less than a second) and do not always show up either.

This is not limited to one particular application but rather to all Desktop applications. The uninstall shortcuts are present, they are just not visible in the start menu anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 seems to have dropped listing uninstall applications in the start menu separately and instead offers an "integrated" uninstall option. This option can be revealed by simply right clicking a start menu shortcut ( example: http://prntscr.com/csklqu).

Almost all software comes packed with uninstaller and thus should list in the right click of the start menu. When this is not the case, luckily any *installed* programs appear in your "Programs and Features" overview  in your windows.

You can easy access it by pressing 'windows key + x' and selecting the top option on the menu that appears, alternatively you could open start and just search for  "programs and features".

The application you wish to uninstall is hopefully listed there and thus allowing you to remove it.

If this does not help or work you could try tools that assist in removing software from your computer such as "iobit uninstaller"

I hope this helps